# How to migrate from HTTPS to SSH github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I cloned my company project repo using HTTPS, I want to migrate into SSH because it conflicts with my personal git account. how can I migrate into SSH instead of using HTTPS?

Comment: FYI you can clone directly using ssh when copying the URL - github allows you to select the URL format from a list of 3 options (as of 2022): https, ssh, or github cli

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Create an ssh key `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Enter passcode and then copy it `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` If you don't have pbcopy, xclip or vim just type: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

add it into your GitHub
[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

2. remove GitHub credentials (if u were using HTTPS there is a high possibility GitHub credentials are saved in your system), we don't need those credentials since we are using SSH *(Optional step)*
3. Change the remote URL to SSH

`>git remote set-url origin <SSH url>`

example :  `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo_name.git`

4. Enter the passKey
5. Verify your remote url has been changed `git remote -v`

Comment: Am I supposed to type the SSH url every time manually?

Comment: general form to work out your SSH url:  use `git config --get remote.origin.url` and then transpose `https://<domain>/<user>/<repo_name>.git` to `git@<domain>:<user>/<repo_name>`

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate ssh key, add it to your profile and then change the url

Source: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

#### Generating ssh key

- Open Git Bash.
- Run `ssh-keygen` and follow the on-screen messages (or simply click <kbd>Enter</kbd> till it over)
- Copy the key file (the content of the public key) located in:

  ```
   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

#### Add key to Github

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click Settings.
  [image]
- In the user settings sidebar, click SSH and GPG keys.
  [image]
- Click New SSH key or Add SSH key.
  [image]
- Paste your key into the "Key" field.
  [image]
- Click Add SSH key.
  [image]